Star Alliance Gold Privileges on Turkish Air flight operated by Indigo
I have a Mumbai to Istanbul flight leg where the code is Turkish TK4751 but says Flight Operator is Indigo. The next leg of my flight, from Istanbul to Frankfurt, is entirely on Turkish airlines.
I am a Star Alliance gold member via my Turkish Airlines frequent flyer program ie Miles and Smiles TK Elite. Will I get all my SA Gold privileges such as business class check-in, lounge access etc? Or do they not apply? What is the situation on such flights?
Already I don't seem to be able to select seats for the leg operated by Indigo.

Note that sometimes on codeshares you need to go on the operating carrier's website to pick your seat. In some cases you may need a different PNR (booking reference) which may too may not be available on the ticketing carrier's website. Otherwise if they allow using the e-ticket number that could work.

Does one check in at the counters of the operating carrier? In my case would check in be at indigo or Turkish?

You look at the screens at the airport :-) But it should be Indigo.

Per the Turkish Airlines website, since you're a TK elite member and flying a TK codeshare, your privileges are available on Indigo:

Miles&Smiles members enjoy benefits on their codeshare flights operated by IndiGo Airlines. Enter your membership number during booking your ticket on Turkish Airlines website and enjoy the privileges according to your tier level.
These privileges only apply to Turkish Airlines marketed and IndiGo operated flights.
Priority Check-in and Priority Baggage
Lounge Access
Meal on Board
Premium Seating
Check-in Baggage Allowance

https://www.turkishairlines.com/de-int/miles-and-smiles/program-partners/airlines/Indigo/

does that apply to other Star Alliance status holders or only Turkish "Miles & Smiles" itself?

@mlc I believe only for TK elite members, but the OP specified they are one.

aah sorry i misread the OP

Thanks. Indeed i am TK Elite
